# drop migration tables after migration ended

Tags: 8, migrations

After uninstall migration modules the tables created not removed and still exist and can not be reasonable to deploy without remove that tables.

**Problem:**

The 3 modules Migrate, Migrate_drupal, Migrate_drupal_ui didn't implement Hook_uninstall() to remove these tables or other data related to migration and have no use after complete migration

[The issue on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2713327)

Answer (score 1):

**Motivation:**

List all tables prefixed with migrate_ in hook_install.
Implement hook_uninstall to remove all tables prefixed with migrate_ except those listed when install the same prefix.

**Solution:**

The migrate core module must list all tables prefixed with migrate_ during installl.
The migrate module must remove all tables prefixed with migrate_ during uninstall.

[drop_migration_tables_during_uninstall.patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/drop_migration_tables_during_uninstall.patch) implemented the hook_install && uninstall hooks in migrate.install to drop all tables prefixed with migrate except those where found during module installation (may be other contributed or custom modules defines tables prefixed with migrate) which is not a good decision

Comment: Can you provide a link to the core (or contrib) issue for this?

Comment: I added the link in the question body